# Plot any parametrization (pure function, numbered variables)

Tags: plotting, variable, pure-function, sequence, arguments

I'd like to write a function `plot[reg_,f_]` that takes as input any product of intervals (list of pairs of reals) `reg`$\subseteq\!\mathbb{R}^d$ and a map/parametrization (pure function) $f:D\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n\!\in\!\{2,3\}$ and $1\!\leq\!d\!\leq\!n$, and plot its trajectory. Examples of use:

```
plot[{{0,2Pi}},               {Cos[#],Sin[#]}&]                                  (*circle*)
plot[{{0,2Pi},{0,1}},         #2{Cos[#1],Sin[#1]}&]                              (*filled circle*)
plot[{{0,2},{0,1}},           {#1,#2}&]                                          (*filled rectangle*)
plot[{{0,2Pi}},               {Sin[#]+2Sin[2#],Cos[#]-2Cos[2#],-Sin[3#]}&];      (*trefoil knot*)
plot[{{0,2Pi},{0,2Pi}},       {(3+Cos[#1])Cos[#2],(3+Cos[#1])Sin[#2],Sin[#1]}&]; (*torus*)
plot[{{0,2Pi},{-Pi,Pi},{0,1}},#3{Cos[#1]Cos[#2],Cos[#1]Sin[#2],Sin[#1]}&];       (*filled sphere*)
```

While writing this question, I wanted to give my attempt at this problem. In the end, I solved it, so I am sharing it below, in hopes it helps someone else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot[reg_,f_] := Module[{tr=Transpose,d=Length@reg,n=Length@f[[1]],v,o}, 
   v = Table[Unique[],{i,d}]; o={f@@v,Sequence@@tr@Prepend[tr@reg,v],PlotRange->All};
   If[n==2,Return[ParametricPlot@@o]];
   If[n==3,Return[ParametricPlot3D@@o]]; ];
```